# Gradle error on Android Studio startup

Tags: gradle, android-studio, android-support-library, build.gradle

Every time I start Android Studio I get the following error:

> Gradle 'VertretungsplanProject' project refresh failed: Could not
>   fetch model of type 'IdeaProject' using Gradle distribution
>   'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.6-bin.zip'. A
>   problem occurred configuring project ':Vertretungsplan'. A problem
>   occurred configuring project ':Vertretungsplan'. Failed to notify
>   project evaluation listener. A problem occurred configuring project
>   ':libraries:actionbarsherlock'. Failed to notify project evaluation
>   listener. Could not normalize path for file
>   'P:\Projekte\VertretungsplanProject\libraries\actionbarsherlock:Vertretungsplan\libs\android-support-v4.jar'.
>   The syntax for the filename, directoryname or the  volume label is
>   wrong

My project looks like this:

[image]

Gradle settings:

[image]

build.gradle of *:Vertretungsplan*:

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.4.jar')
    compile project(':libraries:actionbarsherlock')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }
}
```

build.gradle of *:VertretungsplanProject* is empty.

build.gradle of *:actionbarsherlock*:

```js
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile files(':Vertretungsplan/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 17
    buildToolsVersion "17.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7
        targetSdkVersion 16
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

When I want to compile now this error appears:

> **Deprecated make implementation**
>   Old implementation of "Make" feature is enabled for this project.
>   It has been deprecated and will be removed soon.
>   Please enable newer 'external build' feature in Settings | Compiler.

After changing this setting to `Use external build` everything is working fine.
But this appears every time I start Android Studio and this is really annoying.

## UPDATE

I deleted the `android-support-v4.jar` from the `libs` folder and simply wrote `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'` to the `build.gradle` of ActionbarSherlock. Then the `android-support-v4.jar` is used from the installed SDK.

Comment: Hola.. did u come across any solution @Simon ??

Comment: No still No solution :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**EDIT**

1. Go to `File > Settings > "Build,Execution,Deployment"> Compiler`

Click compiler directly.

2. Check the option: `Use external build` > `Apply` > `OK`.

It worked for me !! :)

Comment: see my last sentence in my question. this is exactly what I meant :p but this appears everytime I start the programm

Comment: Well, after you make the setting, the IDE gives a pop-up of "Update" saying "you have changed..blah blah.." on the right hand top. I made the selection ,"always for ..." and tada... It worked for me !

Comment: heres the exact pop-up : Update Property Files
The structure of following Android modules was changed: facebook google-play-services_lib  Would you like to update related project.properties files? Only once Always for these modules Never for these modules

Comment: @Vera Option isn't there, when i clicked on compiler. All i see is "clear output directory on rebuild"  and "Automatically show first error in editor"

Comment: @Vera Just created a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20277438/cant-compile-new-project-with-upgraded-android-studio-due-to-gradle-dependencie) with all the information you may need.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have more than one issue. Problems loading gradle on startup and problems resolving the dependency path name in your environment.

I recently found a fix for the "Failed to import Gradle project" issue, which could be linked to your dependency issue.

At least if you fix one, you know your issue could specifically be the dependency path resolution rather than a gradle/android studio issue...

Check out the troubleshooting section here:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html#Troubleshooting

The basic steps are:
1. Close android studio
2. Open the SDK manager 
(run android binary/executable which should be in /tools)
3. Scroll down the list and expand extras
4. Tick the "Android Support Repository"
5. Click Install Packages.. etc etc...

You need to download this as Android Studio 0.2.x needs a new maven repository used by the new build system for the support library, instead of using support library jar's.

Let us know if anything changes after trying this fix.

Comment: I had downloaded the support repository. I fixed this issue in another way.  I redownloaded android studio and didn't use the support v4 jar file in my project anymore. I just wrote that I want to use the support file of the sdk and then it works.

Comment: Do you remember where you chose to use the support file of the sdk? Just thinking for someone reading this who is having the same problem..

Comment: Thanks. Slowly getting the hang of gradle vs studio;

Comment: well it's not exactly 'extra' if it doesn't work without it now is it?

Answer (score 1):

In the error message, the path appears: 'P:\Projekte\VertretungsplanProject\libraries\actionbarsherlock\:Vertretungsplan\libs\android-support-v4.jar'

It looks like you're on Windows. The semicolon before Vertretungsplan is not a legal filesystem character. This appears in your script as

```
compile files(':Vertretungsplan/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Try changing this to

```
compile files('Vertretungsplan/libs/android-support-v4.jar')
```

Comment: first it was working fine until I compiled my project. there were about 120 errors. after changing it back I only got this error: ```Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':Vertretungsplan'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > A problem occurred configuring project ':libraries:actionbarsherlock'.
      > Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
         > Could not normalize path for file 'P:\Projekte\VertretungsplanProject\libraries\actionbarsherlock\:Vertretungsplan\libs\android-support-v4.jar'.```